# How to set the default value of a user defined column in SharePoint depending on the content type that uses it

Tags: sharepoint

In a SharePoint website I defined a new column that is used in three different content types. Now I want to define a different default value for this column for each content type. Is this possible using the webservice interface of SharePoint? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set a default value for a column in Sharepoint based on the content type. What you could do though is modify the editform and newform aspx pages of the lists that use the content types / columns and then use JQuery to set the value based on the selected content type.

Comment: +1 Just wanted to add that you don't have to use JQuery... Regular JavaScript will work just fine for something small like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your other option is a custom field where you can run c# code to determine the value of the field based on your particular requirements. Not very light weight to implement however.